# How to add spaces between specific digits when providing phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have input field where user provide his phone number, like that:

```
<label for="phone" class="first-col">Phone No.:</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" />
<span class="form-hint">Proper format "8 600 00 000"</span>
```

I need to make that when user typing number in following:

```
861234567
```

It automatically added spaces in following:

```
8 612 34 567
```

Any ideas how could I achieve It? Using *Java Script* or maybe with *CSS*? Or maybe there is way to achieve It via *HTML*? I've nothing found about that.

Comment: `It automatically added spaces in following (after 1 digit, after 4 digits, after 6 digits):

8 612 34 567`. your sentence and numbers are not matching with each other

Comment: i will prefer to provide three/four boxes along with hyphen to enter phone number

Comment: UI masking is the keyword that you should search on Google.

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution in pure JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener("keyup", function(){
   txt=this.value;
   if (txt.length==1 || txt.length==5 || txt.length==8)
    this.value=this.value+" ";
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
var curchr = this.value.length;
var curval = $(this).val();
if (curchr == 1) {
    $("input[name='phone']").val("" + curval + "" + " ");
} else if (curchr == 4) {
    $("input[name='phone']").val(curval + " ");
}else if (curchr == 8) { 
    $("input[name='phone']").val(curval + " ");
}
```

});